# Aurelia i18n switching between languages slows down view reload

Tags: routes, localization, internationalization, aurelia

I have the following issue - I have a language component which changes the language via the following method:

```
switchLanguage() {
    this.i18n.setLocale(this.selectedLanguage);
    this.router.navigateToRoute('dp', {language:this.selectedLanguage}, { replace: true });
  }
```

This method is called by a select and alternates between two languages. The problem is that if I change the language a few times the loading times get noticeably slower. I need the router to make a full refresh of the page so I can access the activate method of the router and load the new language settings from the back-end. I tested the method and I can see that a delay happens after the setLocale() method has been called. After the delay the router refreshes the page without issues.

If I remove the router redirect from the code altogether the delay disappears and only the bindings are refreshed. That's not the behaviour I need though.

My activation strategy is replace for the particular view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved with the Aurelia 1.0 release.